# Neo4j 1.9 throws "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused" with multi-threaded neocons client

Tags: clojure, neo4j

G'day,

I've written a little program in Clojure that uses [neocons](http://clojureneo4j.info/) to jam a bunch of data into Neo4J v1.9.4, and after getting it working have been tinkering with performance.

On large data sets the bottleneck is inserting relationships into Neo4j, which isn't all that surprising given they have to be done one-at-a-time.  So my thought was to sprinkle some pmap magic on it, to see if some naive parallelism helped.

Unexpectedly (at least to me), that resulted in neocons throwing a "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused" exception, which seems odd given that the client will be defaulting to 10 threads (pmap creates no more than numberOfProcessors + 2 threads), while Neo4j will be defaulting to 80 threads (numberOfProcessors * 10, at least if I'm reading [the docs](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-configuration.html) right).  Last time I checked, 10 was less than 80, so Neo4j should have... <takes off shoes>... lots of threads to spare.

The line of code in question is [here](https://github.com/pmonks/depends/blob/master/src/depends/neo4jwriter.clj#L68) - the only change that was made was to switch the "map" call to a "pmap" call.

Any ideas / suggestions?

Thanks in advance,

Peter

Comment: Note: this issue is occurring (albeit after a longer period, and with larger data sets) even without any use of multi-threading in the client.

Comment: Also, this also occurs on Neo4J v1.9.5 and v2.0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Peter,

I would recommend to use batch-mode for the creation of relationships too. I saw you use batch-creation for the nodes already.

Make sure that your batch sizes is roughly between 20k and 50k elements to be most efficient.

Otherwise you end up with two issues:

1. using one transaction per tx really drains your resources because it does a synchronized forced write to the transaction-log at each commit
2. as creating relationships locks both start and end-nodes you'll get a lot of locks that other threads wait for and so you can easily end up stalling all your server threads who wait for locks to be released on their start or end-nodes

You should see these locked threads by issuing a kill -3 (or jstack ) against the neo4j server.

Batching those relationship-creations and grouping them by subgraphs so that there is as little overlap as possible between the batches should help a lot.

Not related to your issue, but still worth investigating later.

Not sure what neocons uses there under the hood, but you might fare better with the transactional endpoint and cypher in neo4j 2.0.

Comment: Thanks Michael. While one-at-a-time creation of relationships will be slow, it should still work, correct?  My (single-threaded) client app and the admin console webapp are the only clients connected to this server, so I don't think it's stalled threads.  In further support of this, VisualVM's thread view shows each of 4 "acceptor" threads taking turns to respond to the individual relationship create calls (exactly as expected).

Comment: Hmm, it would be interesting to see a thread-dump when the "connection refused" happens. Perhaps it is a Jetty issue. If you do single threaded http-requests for relationship-creation as fire & forget, the n the locking issue might also happen.

Comment: One other note: bulk import of the relationships is not trivial as the logic stands, as some of the target nodes don't yet exist and are (currently) created at the same time as the relationship if they don't.  I could add an intermediate pass to the logic to create those "unknown" target nodes prior to creating any relationships, of course.

Comment: So I switched the logic over to batching (for both node creation and relationship creation) and the ConnectException went away.  The import also got a "tad" faster (like orders of magnitude!).  Thanks Michael!  ;-)